# PUT vs GET speed, is it worth it to do a GET check for changes and then do a PUT?

Tags: php, apache

I am in the middle of a project witch involves syncing a webshop with an external API, i have some hooks in product update etc, and every time a value which is important for the backend API is processed i do:

```
/**
 * localObject parameters must be the same as the ones from the API
 * @param $endpoint
 * @param $objectName
 * @param $identifierKey
 * @param $identifierValue
 * @param $localObject
 * @return bool
 */
private function objectHasChanged($endpoint, $objectName, $identifierKey, $identifierValue, $localObject) {
    $res = $this->request("GET", "/$endpoint?$identifierKey=".$identifierValue);

    if ($res->status !== 200 || !property_exists($res->body, $endpoint))
        return false;
    $BBObject = $res->body->{$endpoint}[0];

    $objectHasChanged = false;
    foreach ($BBObject as $property => $value) {
        if (property_exists($localObject, $property)) {
            if ($value != $localObject->{$property}) {
                $BBObject->$property = $localObject->$property;
                $objectHasChanged = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($objectHasChanged) {
        $this->request("PUT", "/$endpoint/".$BBObject->id, array(
            $objectName => $BBObject
        ));
    }
    return $BBObject;
}
```

This basically queries for a GET which on avg prob returns around 20 items, loops the items against the local copy, and updates the backend if changes are present, would it be faster to just do a PUT every time?

The PUT update also contains about 20 items on avg. The data is JSON.

Comment: it'd be highly racy. two people doing a get at the same time would get the same "go for it!" answer, and then stomp on each others toes the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

If the systems are close (ie. not on veery slow lines), get is always faster than update. (not really, but bear with me).

You see, once the database starts filling up with +10.000 products, updates tends to cost alot. Especially if youre doing it on a busy shop frontend.

(Im gonna assume MySQL as backend to the webservice here).

Its a lot cheaper doing GET's that will consume 20 times the bandwidth (assuming you have the bandwidth), than UPDATE queries. Mostly because SELECT will be answered from mysql's cache. As far as i can tell from mysql documentation, UPDATE does NOT answer from cache and need to go to disk for every query and UPDATE has a lot of potential for causing a table lock while working.

This basically means, that the 20 questions. (or 200, if you need) will be answered from RAM, which is very fast.
Disk IO will probably be your limiting factor on a live shop system.

But to be honest, if i was you i'd try out them both and measure the time spend in each case. Just keep in mind that everything slows down (especially updates) when you get many products.